# Not getting google map in ion item

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on chat application(ionic 3), in which used cordova-plugin-googlemaps.

I need to implement location sharing in my case and need to load map in ion-item in ion-list.

.html file as below,

```
<ion-content class="messages">
<ion-list no-padding *ngIf="user" (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)">
<div *ngFor="let message of chatMessages; let i = index">
  ...
  <ion-item no-lines>
    <ion-label>
      <p *ngIf="message.from == user.uid">
        ... <!--from sender>
      </p>
      <p *ngIf="message.from != user.uid">
        ...<!--from receiver>
      </p>
    </ion-label>
    {{message.message}}
    <div #mapcanvas class="mapcanvas" id="mapcanvas" *ngIf="message.message.substring(0,12) == 'location'"></div>
  </ion-item>
</div>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

map generation code as below,

```
generateMap(latitude: number, longitude: number){
  this.loghandlingProvider.showLog(this.TAG, 'From generate map.');
  this.elementMap = document.getElementById('mapcanvas');
  let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
   camera: {
     target: {
       lat: latitude,
       lng: longitude
     },
   zoom: 18,
   tilt: 30
   }
};
 this.loghandlingProvider.showLog(this.TAG, 'Create map.');
 this.map = GoogleMaps.create(this.elementMap, mapOptions);
 this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
 .then(() => {
   this.loghandlingProvider.showLog(this.TAG, 'Map is Ready To Use');
 }, err => {
   this.loghandlingProvider.showLog(this.TAG, 'Map Error : ' + err);
 });
}
```

Not even getting MAP_READY event.

Comment: is the map visible? any errors in the log?

Comment: @SurajRao not getting any error. if i put div out side list and direct in ion-content then its works.

Comment: then use a div instead of ion-item or maybe ion-row

Comment: i compulsory need to add that in list and tried every thing but not getting map.

Comment: ion-item has a full width and set height.. you may need to override its style in your scss

Comment: i gave 100% width to ion-item for map, but not working.

Comment: I suppose a map should have a fixed height set.

Comment: i already added fixed height for ion-item in which i added map div. Map also contains fixed height.